# Converting Number to Binary String

Tags: c++11

The following is the code to convert a number to binary string. Can anyone tell me how `ans.push_back((char)('0' + rem))` works?

```
class Solution {
public:
    string findDigitsInBinary(int n) {
        string ans;
        if (n == 0) return "0";

        while (n > 0) {
        int rem = n % 2; 
        ans.push_back((char)('0' + rem));
        n /= 2;
        }

        reverse(ans.begin(), ans.end());
        return ans;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand it, you just need to know that you can do arithmetic operations on `char` variables too. So, the simple loop below is valid and will print `0123456789`.

```
for(char c = '0'; c <= '9'; ++c)
    cout << c;
```

In you code, `rem` is either 0 or 1. So, `(char)('0'+rem)` is either `'0'` or `'1'` as desired, corresponding to rem=0, 1, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (n > 0) {
    int rem = n % 2; 
    ans.push_back((char)('0' + rem));
    n /= 2;
}
```

Focus on this loop. Suppose n is 5
`n > 0 true` so enter into loop. `rem = n % 2` so `rem = 5 % 2 = 1`

`ans.push_back((char)('0' + rem))` here `('0' + rem)` is `(48 + 1)` ASCII of `'0'` is 48

Now convert `48 + 1 = 49` into char that is `'1'`. Now push `'1'` into `ans`and then `n /= 2` is `5 /= 2` that is `2`. Now go back and check the condition in while loop. After loop reverse the content of `ans` and you have binary string of number `n`

Answer (score 0):

First you get `rem` as %2. Thus the value of rem can either be 0 or 1.
In `ans.push_back((char)('0' + rem));` you need to add the corresponding character to the string, that is either 0 or 1. For this you have considered '0' as base character and you simply add the rem to it, using its ASCII int. When doing such integer operation, the ASCII value of character '0' is considered, which is 48. Thus after adding rem to it, it can either be 48 + 0 = 48 or 48 + 1 = 49. 
Finally, this value is type casted back to char, with 48 being '0' and 49 being '1'